# What is the intuition behind coefficient of ergodicity?

Tags: probability, ergodic-theory

Let $P$ be an $n\times n$ stochastic matrix, then coefficient of ergodicity $\tau(P)$ is defined as follows:

$$\tau(P) = \frac{1}{2}\max_{i,j} \sum_{k=1}^n|P_{ik}-P_{jk}|=1-\min_{i,j} \sum_{k=1}^n \min(P_{ik},P_{jk})$$

Can someone give me an intuitive insight of this coefficient?

Comment: You can view this as some measure of how similarly different rows of the matrix behave. Namely, a matrix is said to have low ergodicity if there are two elements in the chain such that starting a random walk at either one results in a similar distribution after one step (and therefore after any number of steps), as measured by the l1 distance. In particular, the ergodicity is 0 iff two rows are exactly equal, and is 1 iff all row vectors are orthogonal (i.e. the matrix is a permutation matrix).

Comment: Can be considered as a quantity to determine the number of steps needed to reach stationary distribution?